# You keep me hanging on - phrasal verb(s)?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, continuous-aspect

What is actually the phasal verb in a sentence:
You keep me hanging on
"Keep on" or "hang on"? What do we have here? Double phrasal verb? I am trying to figure this out for a while today... This is the part of the song by Vanilla Fudge and Kim Wilde and others. Thanks.

Comment: Here we have the verb "keep" taking an object and ing clause as complements. In CGEL analysis "on" is seen as an intransitive preposition. "On" can be expanded with an object: She kept me hanging on the phone for five minutes. The verb "keep" enters a number of complementation patterns, some of them involving a sequence of prepositional verbs". For example, "She kept on hanging on in there", "She kept on hanging out with losers" or "She kept on hanging up on me" etc –

Comment: *Keep* is the sentence's verb. *Hanging on* is an object complement for *me*. Compare: *You make me happy.* See [Defining Object Complements](https://www.thoughtco.com/object-complement-grammar-1691355)